# How do I maintain logged in session with golang for scraping?

Tags: go, session-state, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from a website that requires user/password login using go. With python this is simple using `requests` lib:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.post("https://site.com/login", data={ 'username': 'user', 'password': '123456' })

# access URL that requires authentication
resp = session.get('https://site.com/restricted/url')
```

What is a simple way to accomplish the same thing with golang? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Create a custom HTTP [Client](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) instance and attach a [cookie jar](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/) to it.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a scraping framework called [Colly](http://go-colly.org/) which handles HTTP sessions out of the box. You can achieve the mentioned functionality similarly:

```
c := colly.NewCollector()
c.Post("https://example.com/login", map[string]string{"user": "x", "pass": "y"})
```

The code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/asciimoo/colly).
A complete example of handling authentications is also [available](http://go-colly.org/docs/examples/login/).